# Does Django first evaluate __init__.py files in site-packages before my own apps?

Tags: python, django

I want to monkey-patch a library that's in my Django project's `site-packages`, and it seems like the logical place to do this is in an `__init__.py` file in one of my Django apps. But, if Django doesn't guarantee to run the `__init__.py` files in `site-packages` before my own packages, wouldn't this cause a race condition on startup?

Or maybe the act of monkey-patching will automatically cause python to first load the referenced module that I want to patch, rendering this question moot?

Comment: It looks like Django will load apps from anywhere, site-packages or otherwise, in the order they are listed in the ```INSTALLED_APPS``` setting. Called by django/core/wsgi.py get_wsgi_application(): django/__init__.py setup(): https://github.com/django/django/blob/8047e3666b0b50bb04e6f16c2a4fb21ddfd5713f/django/__init__.py

Comment: Though this doesn't answer the more general question of how to monkey-patch a python package in ```site-packages``` which is not, or does not contain, a Django app.

Comment: Paste your code. What are you monkey patching  and why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to monkey-patch a library before Django loads, you need to monkey-patch the library before Django loads :)

If you're using Gunicorn, the place to do this monkey-patching would likely be either in a custom [pre_fork()](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#pre-fork) or [post_fork()](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#post-fork) server hook. The hook function must be defined in a python file given to gunicorn with the [config](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#config) option. For instance, it's common to monkey-patch `psycopg2` (Postgres python library) in the `post_fork()` hook if you're using `gevent`. Both of these hooks are run before the Django application is loaded, unless you use the [preload](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#preload-app) option.

If you use the `preload` option, then you'll have to use the [on_starting()](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#on-starting) or [when_ready()](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#when-ready) hooks, because in the preload flow Django loads *before* the `pre_fork()` and `post_fork()` hooks are called. Keep in mind that you could use these hooks in the non-preload case too, but these hooks are called while gunicorn is still initializing things, whereas it's good practice to limit the scope of monkey-patching to prevent unintended side effects.